# Improve feedback possibilty for front-page suggestions

Tags: feature-request, front-page

After scanning the frontpage once I have some idea about which questions I do not want to even read, because the title may tell me that while the tags are not uninteresting, the particular details are not my speciality.

Still, next time I visit the front page, likely many questions will still appear. It would be nice if I had more influence on future suggestions.

I know I can influence by using tag favourites and ignores, but that seems a bit coarse.

Either by letting me point out questions not to be shown to me on the front-page anymore, or by letting me give feedback on suggested questions that influence the recommendation engine.